# Rank of ordinal number

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-induction

How do I show that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(\alpha)=\alpha
$$
for all ordinals $\alpha? I've attempted to solve this via transfinite induction but I could not get it right.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Transfinite induction is the way to go. When you tried that, where did you get stuck?

Comment: It is clear in x=0. when I assume true for all ordinal less than or equal, but I I do not how I can do next step

Answer (score 5):

Fix an ordinal $\alpha$, and assume that $\mathrm{rank}(\beta)=\beta$ for all $\beta < \alpha$.

- If $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal, then $\alpha=\beta^+$ for some ordinal $\beta < \alpha$. But then $\alpha = \beta \cup \{ \beta \}$. Apply the definition of rank, using the assumption that $\mathrm{rank}(\beta)=\beta$.
- If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \beta$. Now, again, use the definition of rank, together with the assumption that $\mathrm{rank}(\beta)=\beta$ for all $\beta < \alpha$.

The result then follows by transfinite induction.

Comment: Using the $\beta^+$ to denote the successor ordinal is just awful, and I will continue complaining about it until the end of time.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why? Doesn’t it match the successor cardinal notation?

Comment: @user76284: Absolutely not! For example, $\omega = \aleph_0$, but $\omega^+ = \omega \cup \{ \omega \}$ is countable and $\aleph_0^+ = \aleph_1$ is uncountable. Since I wrote this answer (over two years ago) I've stopped using $(-)^+$ for successor ordinals (with the exception of defining successor sets $x^+ = x \cup \{ x \}$... still battling with that one).

Comment: @CliveNewstead But we already treat cardinals and ordinals differently depending on their notation. For instance, $\aleph_0 \cdot 2 = \aleph_0$ but $\omega \cdot 2 \neq \omega$. If we already switch the meaning of $+$ and $\cdot$ to what is most natural in each context, why can't we do the same for $(\cdot)^+$?