# Inaccessible cardinal and well founded set

Tags: model-theory, axioms, large-cardinals

How can I prove the following fact?
 Let be a regular cardinal $\kappa$ such that $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC. Then $\kappa$ is inaccessible.

Comment: Note that the proof that $\kappa$ is a strong limit doesn’t use the regularity of $\kappa$. So a more informative wording would be “if $V_{\kappa}$ is a model of ZFC then $\kappa$ is a strong limit.” (So of course if $\kappa$ also happens to be regular, then it is inaccessible.)

Answer (score 1):

Since we assume $\kappa$ to be regular, we only need to prove that for any $\lambda < \kappa$ we have $2^\lambda < \kappa$. Note that for every ordinal $\alpha$ we have $\operatorname{rank}(\alpha) = \alpha$ (see, e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2463996/661457)). In particular, that means that the collection of ordinals in $V_\kappa$ is just $\kappa$. So for $\lambda < \kappa$, we have $\lambda \in V_\kappa$ and all of its subsets belong to $V_\kappa$. Then since $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC, the powerset $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ must belong to $V_\kappa$ again. Thus $2^\lambda$ (as an ordinal) is also in $V_\kappa$, and so we see $2^\lambda < \kappa$.

Comment: The question asks about regular $\kappa$ and a regular wordly cardinal is inaccessible

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thanks for pointing that out, I did not read properly. Hopefully my answer now makes sense and actually answers the question.

Comment: @Mark Kamsma Thank you. However, here I’m assuming that k is regular. So I’m not considering the case in which k is the least worldly cardinal. So the statement should be correct but I’ve no idea how to prove that.

Comment: @SeTh Refresh the page ;) Alessandro pointed this out as well, and I edited. Hopefully it now actually answers your question.

Comment: You don’t need satisfaction of ZFC to show $\lambda$’s power set is an element (and also that does not imply it for general transitive models).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I also remarked that every subset of $\lambda$ is in $V_\kappa$ (this is indeed a direct consequence of the particular way we build $V_\kappa$). Then $V_\kappa$ satisfies that the collection of all subsets (it knows of) of $\lambda$ is again a set. Every subset of $\lambda$ will be in that collection, so $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ is a set in $V_\kappa$. I feel like that is a valid argument, or am I missing something?

Comment: I missed the part about every subset, so there is no gap there. But it remains it being a model of ZFC is unnecessary except inasmuch as, say, pairing implies $\kappa$ is a limit ordinal. The argument is simply that $P(\lambda)\in V_{\lambda +2}$. However the fact that it satisfies ZFC is necessary for arguing there is an ordinal in $V_\kappa$ in bijective correspondence with the power set. (The fact the minimal such ordinal agrees with the one in the universe is a simple but unnecessary additional argument.)